# create image gallery in android with thumbnail navigation

Tags: android, image, navigation, gallery

i want create a image gallery with thumbnail navigation as screen shot below in android.
already all of thumbnail images must be in horizontal scroll view and when click on thumbnail , Original size will be shown . how can do this with view switcher.
please help me.
best regards

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Load all your images in an arraylist and when you click on next arrow shown in the image, disaply the image and increment counter if image counter is greater than list size, then it was last image displayed.

If you click on back button always decrement your image counter.

Comment: thanks for answer . but i want create current this view and want make image gallery with view switcher . and already all of thumbnail images must be in horizontal scroll view and when click on thumbnail , Original size will be shown